# Google Apps Script PropertiesService - Confused by unreliable Executions logging & editor debugging

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-apps-script, stackdriver

I find `PropertiesService` to be unreliable, but probably I'm just not familiar with Google Apps Script or Stackdriver and made a mistake or assumed something here that may caused the problem.

Here's the script:

```
sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties()
sp.setProperties({
  'somekey': 'value'
})
props = sp.getProperties()

console.log(props.toString())
```

And here's the logs before I wrote this SO question:

```
Type     Start Time                 Duration  Status     Stackdriver Log
Trigger  Oct 9, 2020, 11:19:07 PM   0.541 s   Completed  Debug [object Object]
Editor   Oct 9, 2020, 11:11:43 PM   0 s       Unknown    Debug [object Object]
Editor   Oct 9, 2020, 11:08:09 PM   0 s       Unknown    Debug [object Object], ScriptProperties
Editor   Oct 9, 2020, 11:05:16 PM   0 s       Unknown    Debug [object Object], ScriptProperties
```

The one marked as `Editor` type is manual debug runs from apps script web IDE, I set `onTrigger` every 15mins before I added those `PropertiesServices` lines. Whenever I check the `Execution` log page in each execution, it takes minutes to get the log result, and just now, more than half an hour in the future, I re-checked and those `Unknown` status logs are marked `Completed` and all under 0.5s.

Is this just a glitch? If it's not normal or I made a mistake/wrong assumption, what am I supposed to do to ensure I don't experience this kind of unpredictable results?

Why don't I get strings from the `props` key value pair?

Comment: I've been using `PropertiesService` for storing project configs since the day I've started working with GAS, and I am yet to see *any* issues with it. What is that you find unreliable about it exactly?

Comment: If the issue is responsiveness/reliability of the logging **within** Apps Script, you can always send feedback from within the script.google.com site, its not really a question that can be answered here. Though as TheMaster says, Google does offer a way of getting better logging. Also, as Oleg Valter and Cooper are saying, just because it doesn't show up on the logs immediately, doesn't mean its not working or is unreliable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For relatively better and reliable logging, Use Stackdriver directly(i.e., View> Stackdriver logging) rather than from the "executions" page in the dashboard.  To do this, you need to [switch  Google cloud project from default to standard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project) by setting a custom project number in  Resources > Cloud Platform project > Change project.
- When logging objects, You must always `JSON.stringify` the object before feeding it to `console`. `props.toString()` will only return `[object Object]` as that  is it's internal structure.

```js
/*<ignore>*/console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false,autoScroll:false});/*</ignore>*/
const props = {a:1};
console.log(props.toString());//[object Object]
console.log(JSON.stringify(props));//{"a":1}
```

```html
<!-- https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375985/ -->    <script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So you're saying the logging is unreliable for non Cloud Platform Apps Script that by default uses Executions? I think I need to try the JSON.stringify() _and_ manually check the Script Properties to see if it's mosty logging problem or somehow tied to PropertiesService, probably tomorrow as it's quite late now.

Comment: To clarify, I've spent days now dealing with JS (which really hates me as much as I hate it), to write to multiple files in GDrive but I rarely have this kind of problem, at most at I would get Failed status when I made mistakes either syntax or because I can't intuit how they structured their API classes & methods to be used because they made it in Java (which I can't stand probably more than JS lol). And since it's IO bound when it successfully ran it took almost a minute to finish, but IIRC never ambiguously says `Unknown` status for 30 minutes or so

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work just fine:

```
function testprops() {
  let sp = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  sp.setProperties({'somekey': Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyy:MM:dd HH:mm:ss")});
  let props = sp.getProperties();
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(props.somekey), "View Properties");
}
```

Comment: The problem is I don't intend (I think I've never even had a situation when I need to) use any UI for Apps Script, so logging & programmatic feedback is important. It's not important enough that I'd be paying for it, but it's important enough that if I can't use PropertiesService reliably then I won't use it in this toy project or any future projects.

Comment: The use of a dialog is just to show that the PropertiesService is working.  I've never had any problems with it.  The only issue that I had was for an application where I wanted to store really long strings greater than 26K.  It might be possible for you to use CacheService if you're just interested in short term storage.