# Why does Logger.log statements not show up in Logs?

Tags: debugging, logging, google-apps-script, v8

I've just transitioned to V8 of google apps script. I'm updating my previous scripts. all of my `Logger.log("Hello World");` statements behave differently. Previously i could hit ctrl+enter which would bring up the "Logs" screen. Currently those logger statements don't show up there and I get a message that "No Functions have been run in this editor session". I am able to open the executions screen and find the Logger statements there. The problem with that few is it only time stamps to the second. Previously the "Logs" screen would time stamp down to the 1000th of a second.

Comment: Did you run a function in this editor session?

Comment: I suggest making a report on Google'e [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com) under the Apps Script component as there's little that the Stackoverflow community can do about this. There appears to have been a lot of issues with Logger since V8.

Comment: @TheMaster - I've run a script which included Logger.log Statements and these statements show up under view -> executions. I believe these should count as functions. Also, as noted previously, this worked without issue in V7.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo - I will do that now. Thanks. I realized StackOverflow  wouldn't fix a bug but given my inexperience I thought it might be a simple error on my part that people had run into before. Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: Apparently this is a change and is working as it's supposed to. Only Script run directly from the editor will go into the "Logs" screen and all others (such as triggering a script from a google sheet) must be tracked in executions. Does anyone have a solution to improve the timestamp issue and get it to display 1/1000ths of a second. One second intervals aren't precise enough to optimize efficiency of the code...

Comment: Try stackdriver logging.. you may need to switch your gcp. Look into my last 5-10 answers.

Comment: After reading a bit about GCP and stackdriver logging I believe this is a paid product (admittedlly with a 90 day trial) that I'd need to purchase. I'm a single user tinkering with code as a hobby. I'm not interested in spending any cash at this stage. I'd hoped there was a free option.

Comment: No it's not paid.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64284233

Comment: @TheMaster - I was able to get this going. I apologize I was mistaken while setting up the OAuth. I thought it was worded that I needed GSuite. Again, thank you for the assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a change and is working as it's supposed to. Only Script run directly from the editor will go into the "Logs" screen and all others (such as triggering a script from a google sheet) must be tracked in executions. If scripts are run directly from the editor they do show up in the "Logs" Screen and this does still timestamp down to 1/1000th of a second. Items tracked in the executions screen are limited to every second which is also an intended behavior at this time.

Comment: It doesn't answer *"Logs" screen would time stamp down to the 1000th of a second*

Comment: @TheMaster - Edited to explain the current behavior of Logs vs Executions regarding time stamping.