# What is the difference between **Apps Script Dashboard** and **view | executions**?

Tags: google-apps-script

With V8 I was coding console.log("whatever") in my script and after I run it select View | Stackdriver logging. Then I get an alert

> View in Dashboard Stackdriver logs for this project are now available
> in the **Apps Script Dashboard**.
>
> If you'd like to view these logs in the Google Cloud Platform, you'll
> need to setup a different project for this script.

where "**Apps Script Dashboard**" is a link to see the execution and usually anything I wrote with console.log.

The logging is not always present in the execution instance. I have noticed a substantial time delay at times. In those cases I use SlidesApp.getUi().alert("whatever") because "WHO HAS TIME?".

How do you go directly to **Apps Script Dashboard** without going to the alert and selecting the link.

I have now switched to Logger.log(whatever) and go to **view | executions**. There is still occasionally a substantial time delay.

What is the difference between  **Apps Script Dashboard**  and **view | executions**?

What is the difference between console.log and Logger.log?

Similar to [Why does Logger.log statements not show up in Logs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305032/why-does-logger-log-statements-not-show-up-in-logs/64373340#64373340)

Comment: Nothing really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the question

> How do you go directly to Apps Script Dashboard without going to the alert and selecting the link.

Go to https://script.google.com. Then navigate from the to the corresponding executions page for your project.

> What is the difference between Apps Script Dashboard and view | executions?

Nothing

> What is the difference between console.log and Logger.log?

Logger.log is older, console.log is newer, besides that, while using Chrome V8, nothing.

Comment: Thank you very much Rubén. There are so many examples online created as the software continues to change. I am sure I am picking up out-of-date ideas a bit too often.